# HTCondor refuses to start it's daemons with exit code 4/NOPERMISSION

Tags: cluster-computing, condor

I have successfully installed HTCondor on the master node and this allows job submission, however the job sits in the queue.

I followed the same approach to install HTCondor on the first node, but was not presented with the configuration wizard. If I alter the provided condor_config file to add the sub-daemon list then HTCondor refuses to start with

> condor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION

Any addition of the DAEMON_LIST parameter stops the cluster daemons from starting.

I am a noob to HTCondor so any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condor_master process starts all the condor services specified in the DAEMON_LIST configuration parameter.  The condor_master logs everything it does to the file /var/log/condor/MasterLog.  Can you look in the file for a hint of what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks - once I found the master log I resolved the issues as they were described.

Comment: What was the error if you recall ? thanks